# How does the errors/[THEME]/404.phtml get called for 404 pages

Tags: 404-page

when we get a 404 by going to something like www.yoursite.com/cowsaremyfriends you get the cms page that has been set as the 404 page in the backened

however, in the errors folder, there is a 404.phtml, what i've been tasked to do i set up the 404 page so that instead of it just being a dead end it's a bit more smarter like suggesting what page you might have been trying to go to

i am wondering how does this 404.phtml page gets called over the CMS one set in the backened as it would be easier to pull off what i am trying to do in that rather than a CMS page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to read [Magento's Many 404 Pages](http://alanstorm.com/magentos_many_404_pages).  It outlines the various ways Magento can 404 on you, including the page you're talking about.

The short version: The 404 page in the `errors` folder (that's `errors/404.php`, which ultimately includes the `404.phtml` file), will render if some piece of Magento code throws a  `Mage_Core_Model_Store_Exception` exception, that exception is uncaught, and Magento isn't running in developer mode.

My quick untested way to achieve your goal would be to get your CMS 404 page to throw a `Mage_Core_Model_Store_Exception`.

Comment: i read though the page, i didn't realize there was a fall back if there was no 404 CMS, after i changed the URL Key of the 404 CMS to be no-route-old i was able to get the fall back template, this one would actually be better to use as i have better access to the collections rather than the 404.phtml file in errors/[THEME]/404.phtml, and if i still need to get the 404.phtml file i can throw the exception in no-rote.phtml, thanks Alan